# scriptScoreQuery implementation in elastic4s

Tags: elasticsearch-7, elastic4s, sksamuel

I use elastic 7.6 and Elastic4s client 7.6.0
I am working on a feature in that requires to change the **‘_score‘** of a subQuery in a bigger one:
in all my big query would look something like this :

```
{"query": {
    "function_score": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "bool": {..}
                    },
                    {
                        "match": {}
                      ....
                     {
                       "script_score": {
                            "query": {
                                "match_phrase": {
                                    ...
                                    }
                             },
                            "script": {
                                "source": "..."
                                     }
                            }
                        },
          **more script queries** ...
 }}, 
       "max_boost": 3.4028235e+38,
        "score_mode": "sum",
        "boost_mode": "sum",
        "functions": [ /some functions"]
    }
}
```

so looking in **elastic4s** i found that there is a class that corresponds to what i want to achieve :

```
case class ScriptScoreQuery(script: String) extends Query
```

unfortunatly this means that it hasn't been implemented yet and i tried to work around it by using script_score feature confined with a filter like this :

```
ScriptScore( Script("_score * 2"),
    weight = Some(defaultBoostValue),
    Some(MatchPhrase(
      field = "someField",
      value = "keyword",
      slop = Some(0),
      boost = Some(defaultBoostValue)
    ))
```

this was translated using *elastic4s* like this :

```
{
      "script_score": {
        "script": {
          "source": "_score * 2"
        }
      },
      "weight": 1,
      "filter": {
        "match_phrase": {
          "someField": {
            "query": "keyword",
            "slop": 0,
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

vs what i need :

```
{
  "script_score": {
        "query": {
            "match_phrase": {
                    "someFields": {
                        "query": "keyword",
                        "slop": 0,
                        "boost": 1
                        }
                    }
            },
        "script": {
            "source": "_score) * 2"
            }
        }
},
```

After using the **explain** api it showed that the ‘_score‘ used is that of the global query, and it's not quite what i need

Is there a way to have an implementation that corresponds to the script score query introduced in elastic 7.0 ?